# Exception happens on http GET request to both http and https API server in flutter web app

Tags: node.js, flutter, https, flutter-web

My API server can serve flutter mobile app but the flutter web app.
To dig deeper on the problem situation, I wrote a flutter-http-test app ([/lib/http_test_body.dart](https://github.com/Racinggavin/flutter-http-test/blob/master/lib/http_test_body.dart)) to figure out the root cause.

Here to run my [Flutter web app test link](http://qccm.hopto.org:3001/)

When test app runs to the statement

```
final resp = await http.get(url);
```

responses success on both iPhone and android
but exception happened on chome and web-server. 
But the external link: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1
was success on all platforms.
I wonder is there any restrictions on building the api server to serve flutter web app?

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/web#implementing-cors

Comment: thanks Spatz, just need this information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the issue post on hapi source [Link](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/3792) and the https://hapi.dev/api. The default CORS configuration of hapi framework is disabled (no CORS headers). Then I add relevant options in the JSON manifest of Glue hapi server configuration composer as below and everything is fine.

```
server: {
...

  routes: {
    cors: {
      origin: 'ignore'
    }
  }
```